# Using an API to obtain JSON data and get the date string and determine if data is stale

Tags: datetime, json, api, perl

This is a nagios check that will use an API URL, get JSON data, flatten the data into a usable perl hash, and ultimately obtain a date string. Once the date is obtained, it should recognize the `strftime` format based on user input and determine the delta hours or minutes. Once the delta time is calculated, it should return critical, warning, or OK, based on the `-c` or `-w` user inputs. I just started Perl a week ago and need some code review to become better at it.

[Gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/Jedimaster0/check_http_freshness)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Getopt::Std;
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';
use JSON::Parse 'assert_valid_json';
use Hash::Flatten qw(:all);
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $plugin_name = "Nagios check_http_freshness";
my $VERSION = "1.0.0";
my $dateNowUTC = DateTime->now;
my $verbose = 0;
$Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION = "true";
# nagios exit codes
use constant EXIT_OK            => 0;
use constant EXIT_WARNING       => 1;
use constant EXIT_CRITICAL      => 2;
use constant EXIT_UNKNOWN       => 3;
#parse cmd opts
my %opts;
getopts('U:K:F:u:t:w:c:z:v', \%opts);
$opts{t} = 60 unless (defined $opts{t});
$opts{w} = 12 unless (defined $opts{w});
$opts{c} = 24 unless (defined $opts{c});
$opts{F} = "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S" unless (defined $opts{F});
$opts{u} = "hours" unless (defined $opts{u});
$opts{z} = "UTC" unless (defined $opts{z});
if (not (defined $opts{U}) || not (defined $opts{K}) ) {
    print "[ERROR] INVALID USAGE\n";
    HELP_MESSAGE();
    exit EXIT_UNKNOWN;
}
if (defined $opts{v}){$verbose = 1;}
if ($opts{w} >= $opts{c}){
    print "[ERROR] Warning value must be less than critical value.\n"; HELP_MESSAGE(); exit EXIT_UNKNOWN;
}
if (not ($opts{u} eq "hours") && not ($opts{u} eq "minutes")){
    print "[ERROR] Time unites must be either hours or minutes.\n"; HELP_MESSAGE(); exit EXIT_UNKNOWN;
}
# Configure the user agent and settings for the http/s request.
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent('Mozilla');
$ua->protocols_allowed( [ 'http', 'https'] );
$ua->parse_head(0);
$ua->timeout($opts{t});
my $response = $ua->get($opts{U});
# Verify the content-type of the response is JSON
eval {
    assert_valid_json ($response->content);
};
if ( $@ ){
    print "[ERROR] Response isn't valid JSON. Please verify source data. \n$@";
    exit EXIT_UNKNOWN;
} else {
    # Convert the JSON data into a perl hashrefs
    my $jsonDecoded = parse_json($response->content);
    my $flatHash = flatten($jsonDecoded);
    if ($verbose){print "[SUCCESS] JSON FOUND -> ", Dumper($flatHash), "\n";}
    if (defined $flatHash->{$opts{K}}){
        if ($verbose){print "[SUCCESS] JSON KEY FOUND -> ", $opts{K}, ": ", $flatHash>{$opts{K}}, "\n";}
        NAGIOS_STATUS(DATETIME_DIFFERENCE(DATETIME_LOOKUP($opts{F}, $flatHash->{$opts{K}})));
    } else {
        print "[ERROR] Retreived JSON does not contain any data for the specified key: $opts{K} \nUse the -v switch to verify the JSON output and use the proper key(s).\n";
        exit EXIT_UNKNOWN;
    }
}
sub DATETIME_LOOKUP {
    my $dateFormat = $_[0];
    my $dateFromJSON = $_[1];
    my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
        pattern   => $dateFormat,
        time_zone => $opts{z},
        on_error  => sub { print "[ERROR] INVALID TIME FORMAT: $dateFormat OR TIME ZONE: $opts{z} \n$_[1] \n" ; HELP_MESSAGE(); exit EXIT_UNKNOWN; },
    );
    my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime($dateFromJSON);
    if (defined $dt){
        if ($verbose){print "[SUCCESS] Time formatted using -> $dateFormat\n", "[SUCCESS] JSON date converted -> $dt $opts{z}\n";}
        return $dt;
    } else {
        print "[ERROR] DATE VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED. Pattern or timezone incorrect."; exit EXIT_UNKNOWN
    }
}
# Subtract JSON date/time from now and return delta
sub DATETIME_DIFFERENCE {
    my $dateInitial = $_[0];
    my $deltaDate;
    # Convert to UTC for standardization of computations and it's just easier to read when everything matches.
    $dateInitial->set_time_zone('UTC');

    $deltaDate = $dateNowUTC->delta_ms($dateInitial);
    if ($verbose){print "[SUCCESS] (NOW) $dateNowUTC UTC - (JSON DATE) $dateInitial ", $dateInitial->time_zone->short_name_for_datetime($dateInitial), " = ", $deltaDate->in_units($opts{u}), " $opts{u} \n";}
    return $deltaDate->in_units($opts{u});
}
# Determine nagios exit code
sub NAGIOS_STATUS {
    my $deltaTime = $_[0];
    if ($deltaTime >= $opts{c}){print "[CRITICAL] Delta $opts{u} ($deltaTime) is >= ($opts{c}) $opts{u}. Data is stale.\n"; exit EXIT_CRITICAL;}
    elsif ($deltaTime >= $opts{w}){print "[WARNING] Delta $opts{u} ($deltaTime) is >= ($opts{w}) $opts{u}. Data becoming stale.\n"; exit EXIT_WARNING;}
    else {print "[OK] Delta $opts{u} ($deltaTime) are within limits -c $opts{c} and -w $opts{w} \n"; exit EXIT_OK;}
}
sub HELP_MESSAGE {
    print <<EOHELP
    Retrieve JSON data from an http/s url and check an object's date attribute to determine if the data is stale.
    --help      shows this message
    --version   shows version information
    USAGE: $0 -U http://www.convert-unix-time.com/api?timestamp=now -K url -F %s -z UTC -c 24 -w 12 -v
    -U        URL to retrieve. (required)
    -K        JSON key to look for date attribute. (required)
    -F        Strftime time format (default: %Y%m%dT%H%M%S). For format details see: man strftime
    -z        Timezone that for the JSON date. Can be "UTC" or UTC offset "-0730"  (default is UTC)
                Can also be "Ameraca/Boston" See: http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-TimeZone/lib/DateTime/TimeZone/Catalog.pm
    -w        Warning if data exceeds this time. (default 12 hours)
    -c        Critical if data exceeds this time. (default 24 hours)
    -u        Time unites. Can be "hours", or "minutes". (default hours)
    -t        Timeout in seconds to wait for the URL to load. (default 60)
    -v        Verbose output.
EOHELP
;}
sub VERSION_MESSAGE {
print <<EOVN
    $plugin_name v. $VERSION
    Copyright (C) 2016 Nathan Snow
    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.
    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.
    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
EOVN
;}
```

Comment: Please do not invalidate answers by editing your question with the updated code.  Ask a new question if you want your new code reviewed.

Comment: Is this acceptable? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148796/perl-nagios-plugin-to-query-an-api-obtain-date-from-json-and-determine-if-the

Comment: Yep, looks nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may also want to look at the [Nagios::Plugin](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Nagios-Plugin/lib/Nagios/Plugin.pm) module or it's successor, [Monitoring::Plugin](http://search.cpan.org/~nierlein/Monitoring-Plugin-0.39/lib/Monitoring/Plugin.pm).

In these plugins, the OK, WARNING, CRITICAL and UNKNOWN exit statuses are exported by default, so you do not need to declare them.

To initiate a plugin, you need something like this:

```
my $plugin = Nagios::Plugin->new(
   shortname => $PLUGIN_NAME, # Short name of your plugin
   usage => $USAGE, # Your usage message
   version => $VERSION # Version number
);
```

Then you can add your command line options thus:

```
$plugin->add_arg("w=i", "-w <hours>\n   Warning if data exceeds this time", 12, 1);
$plugin->add_arg("c=i", "-c <hours>\n   Critical if data exceeds this time", 24, 1);
$plugin->getopts();
```

and so on. The arguments for the `add_arg()` method are `spec`, `usage`, `default` and `required`.

You can then compare your result with the warning and critical thresholds. In essence, your `NAGIOS_STATUS` subroutine can be broken down to one simple line:

```
my $status = $plugin->check_threshold(check => $delta_time, warning => $plugin->opts->w, critical => $plugin->opts->c);
```

Or

```
my $threshold = $plugin->set_thresholds(warning => $plugin->opts->w, critical => $plugin->opts->c); # Set threshold so you can use it later
my $status = $plugin->check_threshold(check => $delta_time);
```

Then, to exit with the correct status, you add this line:

```
$plugin->plugin_exit($status, sprintf("Delta time is %s", $delta_time));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Updated: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148796/perl-nagios-plugin-to-query-an-api-obtain-date-from-json-and-determine-if-the

Answer (score 6):

Just a few quick remarks,

```
# $opts{t} = 60 unless (defined $opts{t});
$opts{t} //= 60;
```

(check perldoc perlop for `//` operator)

```
# not ($opts{u} eq "hours")
($opts{u} ne "hours")
```

(`ne` as not equal)

Prefer `and` over `&&` as later is higher precedence operator and is usually used when you want to take advantage of this particular feature (the same goes for `||` vs. `or`).

```
my $ok = eval {
    assert_valid_json ($response->content);
    1;
};
if (!$ok) { #error..
```

(reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2166162/223226)

```
# my $dateFormat = $_[0];
# my $dateFromJSON = $_[1];
my ($dateFormat, $dateFromJSON) = @_;
```

(assign all vars at once from `@_` array)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and explanations. I'll probably make those changes in a little bit.

Comment: Perl Best Practices: "It's safer and more comprehensible to use only high-precedence booleans in conditional expressions ... and then use parentheses when you need to vary precedence". This contradicts your advice to prefer `and` over `&&`.